# Connection between containers

Tags: docker

I build image of flask app. When I try to send request from their container to service all is ok. Then I try to send request from another container.

```
docker network create web_server --driver bridge
docker run -dit --name server --network web_server test_container
docker run -dit --name client --network web_server python:3.8.9-slim-buster
```

And then do `docker inspect web_server`. Their all good.
Then

```
docker attach client

import requests
req = requests.get('http://server:8000/health')
```

There is an error: `Failed to establish new connection`

How could I fix this problem?

There is `Dockerfile` of server image

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8:8.4
WORKDIR /opt/pipeline
COPY . .

ARG MODEL=<link_to_repo>

RUN git clone ${MODEL} model

RUN python setup.py install

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "sh", "./app.sh" ]
```

config file:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8000'
backlog = 1024
workers = 1
worker_class = 'sync'
worker_connections = 1000
timeout = 42
keepalive = 2
reload = True
```

Run flask+gunicor by :
`gunicorn -c config.py server:app`

server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route(rule='/health', methods=['GET'])
def health():
    return '200'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Error log:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='server', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /health (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f4b3690de20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: Is there a more detailed error message?  Can you show the server code that sets up the network listener?  (Is it obvious if it's listening to the container-private 127.0.0.1 localhost interface, or the 0.0.0.0 all-interfaces address?)

Comment: @DavidMaze I add details

Comment: You need to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` in Flask, or else it won't be accessible outside its own container.  The linked question has more details.